# Ajax search results disappear when changing tabs back and forth

Tags: jquery, ajax, tabs

I have a strange problem. I have two tabs laid out as below. The other one will contain static html code and the other one is filled by an ajax search. The search works beautifully as long as the "project-search-results" tab is active, but nothing happens if it's not. This is not the problem though, the problem is that if a user clicks away on to another tab, the search results disappear and the static content reappears. The question is, is there any way to make them stick? I'm using Django on the server side, in case it makes a difference.

I'm using a home-made tabs code from here (also pasted below):
http://papermashup.com/simple-jquery-tabs/
I'm guessing the problem is that "hide" and "show do quite a bit more than I thought.

```
<div class="span6 main-content" id="tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
     <li><a href="#our-goals">Our Goals</a></li>
     <li><a href="#project-search-results">Search Results</a></li>
   </ul>
  <div id="our-goals">
    goals here
  </div>
  <div id="project-search-results">
    search
    <!-- filled with ajax -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Tabs js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tabs div').hide();
    $('#tabs div:first').show();
    $('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');

    $('#tabs ul li a').click(function(){
    $('#tabs ul li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#tabs div').hide();
    $(currentTab).show();
    return false;
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#tabs div').hide();
```

The above statement hides all the div inside tabs div. So you should use
`$('#tabs > div').hide();` so that it only hides top level (direct children) divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/RUk5W/